# token bucket algorithm, rate limiting javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to write an algorithm to prevent more than 5 messages being sent in 8 seconds, I found the formula for the token bucket algorithm in python, so I am trying to implement it with javascript but I am missing one thing.

The `last_check` variable isn't clear to me. If I track 60 seconds in a minute the problem is when it loops back over after the 59th second the math is thrown off.

**First iteration**

If `last_check` = `new Date().getSeconds()` let's say that it's the 33 second in the minute it tracks, we are now comparing to the 33 second.

When the `rateLimit()` function executes it gets the `current` time of when it has been called, a message for example, and the `current` `new Date().getSeconds()` is 40 seconds for example.... 7 seconds after `last_check`

So `time_passed` is now 7 seconds, `last_checked` becomes 40.

*allowance result*

The `allowance` is `7 * (5.0/8.0) = 4.375`.

---

**Where the problem lies**

If `last_checked` stays at 40, and 22 seconds pass until a new message, then the formula for the second iteration below becomes.

**Second iteration**

`current` becomes 2 (40+22) the `new Date().getSeconds()` loops back to 2... `time_passed` is now (2-40) = -38 seconds, `last_checked` is now 2.

*allowance result*

---

The `allowance` is `-38 * (5.0/8.0) = -23.75`.

```
var rate = 5.0; // unit: messages
var per = 8.0; // unit: seconds
var allowance = rate; // unit: messages
var last_check = new Date().getSeconds();

function rateLimit() {
    current = new Date().getSeconds(); // floating-point, e.g. usec accuracy. Unit: seconds
    time_passed = current - last_check;
    last_check = current;
    allowance += time_passed * (rate / per);

    console.log('Current time: ' + current);
    console.log('Time passed: ' + time_passed);
    console.log('Last check: ' + last_check);
    console.log('Allowance: ' + allowance);

    if (allowance > rate) {
        allowance = rate; // throttle
        console.log('throttle');
    }
    if (allowance < 1.0) {
        console.log('discard message');
        return false;
    } else {
        allowance -= 1.0;
        console.log('forward message');
        return true;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wxjfcm5d/47/

Comment: This feels overly complex, couldn't you store information about each click in an array and then flag as spamming if array is larger than 5? Would something like this work? https://jsfiddle.net/wxjfcm5d/52/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `current - last_check`, you need the difference between two dates, not the difference between where the second hand was.

Replace `new Date().getSeconds()` with `new Date().getTime()/1000` (or `new Date().getTime()` but you'd have to replace `var per = 8.0` with `var per = 8000.0`).

This will result in `current - last_check` always being a positive number of  seconds (or milliseconds) rather than negative when the seconds roll over into minutes.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Evilzebra's comment that the solution may be a little convoluted. Based on your needed behaviour I implemented it this way:

```
var ii = 0;
var perMils = per * 1000;
function rateLimit() {
    if (ii <= rate) {
        ++ii;
        setTimeout(function() {--ii;}, perMils);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [flood-protection](https://github.com/yatki/flood-protection) library that i've wrote. It uses [Token Bucket Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket)

**Usage**:

```
import FloodProtection from 'flood-protection';

const floodProtection = new FloodProtection({
    rate: 5, 
    // default: 5, unit: messages
    // IMPORTANT: rate must be >= 1 (greater than or equal to 1)

    per: 8, 
    // default: 8, unit: seconds
});
```

Hope this helps.